# Lombok builder inheritance with Complex Class Structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've read other questions regarding lombok's builder and inheritance but none of the solutions have worked. Using Lombok version 1.18.4 and Java 11.

I'm trying to inherit the parent builder while also satisfying an interface, using only immutable fields. This is my class structure:

#### The Code

```
public interface FooInterface {
    String getFoo();
}
```

The `getFoo` logic is very common across all implementations, so I decided to make an `Abstract` helper to avoid copy-pasting the same code everywhere.

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractFoo implements FooInterface {

    @Builder.Default
    private final String foo = "foo";

}
```

And the actual `Foo` implementation:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class FooTest extends AbstractFoo {
    private final String bar;
}
```

#### 'Win Condition'

I would like Lombok to

1. Recognize fields required by the parent class.
2. Include those fields in the generated Builders of child classes.

In code:

```
final FooInterface fooTest = FooTest.builder.foo("string").bar("string").build();
assertThat("string").equals(fooTest.getFoo());
assertThat("string").equals(fooTest.getBar());
```

#### Attempted Solutions

The problem is, IntelliJ highlights the `@Data` annotation with this error:

> Lombok needs a default constructor in the base class.

If I remove `@Data` from `FooTest` I get this error:

> There is no default constructor available in *base class*.

So I removed the `@SuperBuilder` from `AbstractFoo` and added a manually-created constructor with all the arguments. The error persists. I've tried other things and annotation combinations, but none have worked.

I also tried -in vain- to set all `AbstractFoo` fields to `protected final`, and declare Foo implementations `final` themselves, which would be consistent with my business rules.

Comment: Have you tried it without IntelliJ, i.e. a direct, maven-, or gradle-based build from the console? The problem may be that the IntelliJ Lombok plugin does not support `@SuperBuilder`. See https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SuperBuilder` isn't supported by current version of IntelliJ IDEA plugin yet.

There's an open issue on project's Github tracker - https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/513

Although it's targeted for 0.25 release which has been released just a few days ago -
https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/releases/tag/releasebuild_0.25

Issue still seems to be open and not yet implemented.

I'd suggest to just try version 0.25 and wait for the next release if it won't work.

Comment: I also saw the conspicuous absence of `@SuperBuilder` from the latest release logs. We'll just have to wait then

Comment: It appears that it is now supported in version 0.27. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/